# Auto detection of enumerated port in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, serial-port

I have one desktop application which is communicating with another Device(Monitor) via serial to USB.

I have one communication board which is connecting both the application. It has chip from CP2100 family.

That communication board is powered up by Device(Monitor) and both the application start exchanging the data. But when I'm turn off the Device(Monitor), Port which is enumerated for desktop application is lost and when turn on the device(Monitor), port is comming back but in this case desktop application is not sending the data to Device(Monitor).

I have used serial port setting to get the current port for desktop application.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this function to enumerate the COM port list and while not connected to a device, loop through the com list and try and connect.  If you can connect, see if you get a response back you expect, if you do you know this is the right COM port, otherwise move onto the next COM port.

`string[] serialPortNames = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();`